# What is the cheapest and most direct route from the UK to Malawi?

Tags: air-travel, budget, uk, africa, malawi

I'm researching a trip to Malawi and I'm struggling to find direct flights. I'd be happy to travel from any UK city to anywhere in Malawi.

I've only been able to find flights for around £900 with at least one stop (NBO or JNB) and often two (usually AMS).

I've heard rumours that cheaper flights can be bought from the Malawi side, but have been unable to verify.

Are these the best that can be found and if so which stopping options are the least hassle?

Comment: Cheapest and most direct sound contradictory to me

Comment: 'Cheapest' also differs at different times of the year...

Comment: @DarkLightA odd that flying further and burning more fuel should be cheaper, but I take your point. However, as at the moment all I can find is both indirect and expensive, I'd take either as an improvement :)

Comment: @MarkMayo currently planning autumn, but if there's a drastically cheaper time I'd consider it.

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be a regular flight between [Lilongwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilongwe_International_Airport) and any European airport.

For a same price, I would prefer a routing via Johannesburg. The flights to Ethiopia, Kenya or South Africa usually start in the evening. A flight to Ethiopia is 7 hours, Kenya is 8 hours and South Africa is almost 12 hours. This means that if you fly to Johannesburg you will have quite a decent night rest. If you fly through Addis Ababa or Nairobi, you will have a much shorter sleep. On the other hand, the total journey time via Johannesburg might be a bit longer. But that's not always true.

All this is true if the price does not matter. Ethiopian Airlines has rather competitive prices ...

Comment: There do not seem to be [_any_ regular flights](http://www.nyasatimes.com/2012/03/15/flights-cancelled-in-malawi-over-forex-crisis/) to Lilongwe anymore.

Answer (score 4):

After a little searching the cheapest option I found was through [Ethiopian Airlines](http://www.ethiopianairlines.com/en/default.aspx)

Return flight from LHR to Lilongwe via Addis Ababa comes in at £705.75 (dates searched October 07-22)

There are also flights to Blantyre which seem just a little more expensive, but maybe that's an option to look at as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://skyscanner.ie a number of times for flights to and from Malawi. Usually I end up flying Ethiopian, which has a stopover in Heathrow or Frankfurt - return should be ~€800 (although it's far far more at busier times of the year).